# Magento 1.7.0.2 override adminhtml: Invalid block type

Tags: magento-1.7

I want to override the standard phtml when you edit a product in **magento admin.**

> **File to override:**
>   C:\wamp64\www\regimeproteine\app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\catalog\form\renderer\fieldset\element.phtml

**I have created a module:**

> **File:** C:\wamp64\www\regimeproteine\app\etc\modules\Pro10_Adminshopscope.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Pro10_Adminshopscope>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Pro10_Adminshopscope>
    </modules>
</config>
```

> **File:**
>   C:\wamp64\www\regimeproteine\app\code\local\Pro10\Adminshopscope\etc\config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Pro10_Adminshopscope>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </Pro10_Adminshopscope>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <adminhtml>
                <rewrite>
                    <catalog_form_renderer_fieldset_element>Pro10_Adminshopscope_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Form_Renderer_Fieldset_Element</catalog_form_renderer_fieldset_element>
                </rewrite>
            </adminhtml>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

**> The file that will override the original:**

> C:\wamp64\www\regimeproteine\app\code\local\Pro10\Adminshopscope\Block\Adminhtml\Catalog\Form\Renderer\Fieldset\Element.phtml

This result in a blanco page, if I remove or rename the target, the default element.phtml is used.

**I changed these files for mor info about the error**

> C:\wamp64\www\regimeproteine\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php
>   C:\wamp64\www\regimeproteine\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Config.php

**the log files:**

> exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'invalid block type:
>   Pro10_Adminshopscope_element' in
>   C:\wamp64\www\regimeproteine\app\Mage.php:597

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Method 1**
If you want to change phtml file, you can define your own admin theme in `app\code\local\Pro10\Adminshopscope\etc\config.xml`

```
<config>
    <stores>
        <admin>
            <design>
                <package>
                    <name>default</name>
                </package>
                <theme>
                    <default>your_theme</default>
                </theme>
            </design>
        </admin>
    </stores>
    <modules>
        <Pro10_Adminshopscope>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </Pro10_Adminshopscope>
    </modules>
    <!-- and so on -->
</config>
```

Then copy original `app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\catalog\form\renderer\fieldset\element.phtml` to `app\design\adminhtml\default\your_theme\template\catalog\form\renderer\fieldset\element.phtml`

**Method 2**
If you need to change something in the block `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Form_Renderer_Fieldset_Element`, then your config will look something like this:

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Pro10_Adminshopscope>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </Pro10_Adminshopscope>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <adminshopscope>
                <class>Pro10_Adminshopscope_Block</class>
            </adminshopscope>
            <adminhtml>
                <rewrite>
                    <catalog_form_renderer_fieldset_element>Pro10_Adminshopscope_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Form_Renderer_Fieldset_Element</catalog_form_renderer_fieldset_element>
                </rewrite>
            </adminhtml>
        </blocks>
    </global>   
</config>
```

In your block `app\code\local\Pro10\Adminshopscope\Block\Adminhtml\Catalog\Form\Renderer\Fieldset\Element.php`, you should set the template like so:

```
class Pro10_Adminshopscope_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Form_Renderer_Fieldset_Element extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Form_Renderer_Fieldset_Element
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        return $this->setTemplate('adminshopscope/catalog/form/renderer/fieldset/element.phtml');
    }
}
```

Lastly, you need to create the file `app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\adminshopscope\catalog\form\renderer\fieldset\element.phtml`

Comment: Thanks Kiatng, I used solution 2, and it works.
Only 1 remark: 
file: "Element.php"
<?php 

class Pro10_Adminshopscope_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Form_Renderer_Fieldset_Element extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Form_Renderer_Fieldset_Element
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        return $this->setTemplate('adminshopscope/catalog/form/renderer/fieldset/element.phtml');
    }
}
?>

You forgot "class"

Answer (score 0):

Small adustment:

> **Element.php:**
>   app\code\local\Pro10\Adminshopscope\Block\Adminhtml\Catalog\Form\Renderer\Fieldset\Element.php, "**class**" forgotten before Pro10_Admin....:

```
class Pro10_Adminshopscope_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Form_Renderer_Fieldset_Element extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Form_Renderer_Fieldset_Element
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        return $this->setTemplate('adminshopscope/catalog/form/renderer/fieldset/element.phtml');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

other question: 
how can I use a custom style.css file in this case?

edit file
app\code\local\Pro10\Adminshopscope\etc\config.xml?

Comment: You use method 1 to set the package and theme for the admin layout area. Then you add the file `skin\adminhtml\default\your_theme\boxes.css`. Note that the file name is not `style.css`. However, you can add additional style file in your layout xml file if you wish. You can google on how to do that.